# php form with implode("\n", $email_headers) does not add enter space

Tags: php, enter, implode

I have a php mail code and it does not send with enter spaces. I have to have the utf-8 in email headers or else it does not recognise æøå. I want it to add enter like this:
Name: xxx
Epost: xxx
Nettside: xxx
Telefon: xxx
Melding: xxx
Right now it prints everything in one sentence like: name: xxx epost: xxx...
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    // Get the form fields, removes html tags and whitespace.
    $navn = strip_tags(trim($_POST["navn"]));
    $navn = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$navn);
    $epost = filter_var(trim($_POST["epost"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $henvendelse = trim($_POST["henvendelse"]);
    $nettside = trim($_POST["nettside"]);
    $telefon = trim($_POST["telefon"]);

    // Check the data.
    if (empty($navn) OR empty($henvendelse) OR !filter_var($epost, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: http://www.noorwebdesign.no/index.php?success=-1#form");
        exit;
    } else {
        // Redirect to the index.html page with success code
        header("Location: http://www.noorwebdesign.no/index.php?success=1#form");
    }

    // Set the recipient email address. Update this to YOUR desired email address.
    $recipient = "post@noorwebdesign.no";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "$navn";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Navn: $navn\n";
    $email_content .= "Epost: $epost\n";
    $email_content .= "Nettside:\n$nettside\n";
    $email_content .= "Telefon:\n$telefon\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Melding:\n$henvendelse\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = array("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

    // Send the email.
    mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, implode("\n", $email_headers));

?>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete code sample.

Comment: You're probably looking at the email body using a rich email client which is assuming an html body. As a starting point, try adding "<br>" just before each of the `\n` and see if that helps? Does it show on new lines now?

Comment: It worked, thanks!!